# How to recursively look for sub classes and at the same time aggregate their values?

Tags: python, pandas

Please find my dataframe this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'class': ['class_b', 'class_a', 'class_c', 'class_d'], 'sub_class': ['class_d', None, 'class_e', 'class_a'], 'entities': [5, 1, 7, 6]})
print(df)

     class sub_class  entities
0  class_b   class_d         5
1  class_a      None         1
2  class_c   class_e         7
3  class_d   class_a         6
```

As per the title, I'm just trying to look for subclasses like we do in `os.walk` but I can't figure it out. For example, `class_b` has `class_d` as subclass and this one has also a subclass (`class_a`) and we could have sometimes up to 5 sub levels.

My expected output is this :

```
     class        all_subclass  sum_entites
0  class_a                  []            1
1  class_b  [class_d, class_a]           12
2  class_c           [class_e]            7
3  class_d           [class_a]            7
4  class_e                  []            0
```

I made a bad code below. I was thinking about making a `while` loop and keep mergin until there is no match but it feels not good.

```
df1 = df.merge(df, left_on='sub_class', right_on='class', how="left", indicator=True).filter(like='class')

result = df1.groupby('class_x').apply(lambda x: list(x.dropna().T.values.tolist())).to_dict()

result

{'class_a': [[], [], [], []],
 'class_b': [['class_b'], ['class_d'], ['class_d'], ['class_a']],
 'class_c': [[], [], [], []],
 'class_d': [[], [], [], []]}
```

Do you have any suggestions guys ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be approached as a graph problem using [`networkx`](https://networkx.org):

```
import networkx as nx

# build Series to later map values
# using groupby.sum in case of duplicates
s = df.groupby('class')['entities'].sum()

# create directed graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df.fillna('NONE'), create_using=nx.DiGraph,
                            source='class', target='sub_class')
G.remove_node('NONE')

# for each node, get all descendants and sum the entities
out = pd.DataFrame([(n, (d:=nx.descendants(G, n)),
                    sum(s.get(x, 0) for x in d|{n}))
                    for n in G],
                  columns=['class', 'all_subclass', 'sum_entites'])
```

Output:

```
     class        all_subclass  sum_entites
0  class_b  {class_a, class_d}           12
1  class_d           {class_a}            7
2  class_a                  {}            1
3  class_c           {class_e}            7
4  class_e                  {}            0
```

Graph:

[image]

Comment: Not only I have my solution but I also learn about networkx. You killed it my friend. Thanks.

Comment: I slightly updated the code to handle cases with duplicates in "class"